# Dropwizard put request issues

Tags: java, dropwizard

I am using the dropwizard example on github and I am having trouble implementing the put request.

I have an update sql statement in the Person.java class

```
"@NamedQuery(name = "com.example.helloworld.core.Person.update",query = "UPDATE Person p SET p.start=:start, p.end=:end where p.id=:id")"
```

and in my PersonDAO.java class, I have a method called update

```
public  List<Person>  update(Long id, Person person) {
return list(namedQuery("com.example.helloworld.core.Person.update").setParameter("id",id).setParameter("start",person.getStart())
.setParameter("end",person.getEnd()));}
```

and under PersonResource.java, I have the@put Method,

```
@PUT
@UnitOfWork
public List<Person> updatePerson(@PathParam("personId") LongParam personId,Person person) {
   return peopleDAO.update(personId.get(),person);
}
```

when i test my put method, I get this error

```
INFO   [16:05:33.430] [dw-49 - PUT /people/2] o.h.e.i.StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener -  Session Metrics {
60159 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
0 nanoseconds spent preparing 0 JDBC statements;
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC statements;
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C puts;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)} 
ERROR  [16:05:33.431] [dw-49 - PUT /people/2] i.d.j.e.LoggingExceptionMapper -  Error handling a request: e27fe462c112d5ca 
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.example.helloworld.db.PersonDAO.update(PersonDAO.java:27)
at com.example.helloworld.resources.PersonResource.updatePerson(PersonResource.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

I was wondering if there were any tips on how to do this. Or could someone give some hints on how to implement the put method in the dropwizard example.

Edit:

PersonDAO.java

```
public class PersonDAO extends AbstractDAO<Person> {


public PersonDAO(SessionFactory factory) {
    super(factory);
}

public Optional<Person> findById(Long id) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(get(id));
}   

public Person create(Person person) {
    return persist(person);
}

public  List<Person>  update(Long id, Person person) {
  return  list(namedQuery("com.example.helloworld.core.Person.update").setParameter("id",id)
                                                                      .setParameter("start",person.getStart())
                                                                      .setParameter("end",person.getEnd()));
}
public List<Person> findAll() {
    return list(namedQuery("com.example.helloworld.core.Person.findAll"));
}
}
```

PersonResource.java

```
  @Path("/people/{personId}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public class PersonResource {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonResource.class);
    public final PersonDAO peopleDAO;

    public PersonResource(PersonDAO peopleDAO) {
        this.peopleDAO = peopleDAO;
    }

    @GET
    @UnitOfWork
    public Person getPerson(@PathParam("personId") LongParam personId) {
        return findSafely(personId.get());
    }


    @PUT
    @UnitOfWork
    public List<Person> updatePerson(@PathParam("personId") LongParam personId,Person person) { 
     return peopleDAO.update(personId.get(),person);
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/view_freemarker")
    @UnitOfWork
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public PersonView getPersonViewFreemarker(@PathParam("personId") LongParam personId) {
        return new PersonView(PersonView.Template.FREEMARKER, findSafely(personId.get()));
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/view_mustache")
    @UnitOfWork
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public PersonView getPersonViewMustache(@PathParam("personId") LongParam personId) {
        return new PersonView(PersonView.Template.MUSTACHE, findSafely(personId.get()));
    }

    private Person findSafely(long personId) {
        return peopleDAO.findById(personId).orElseThrow(() -> new NotFoundException("No such user."));
    }
    }
```

Person.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "people")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(
            name = "com.example.helloworld.core.Person.findAll",
            query = "SELECT p FROM Person p"
        ),
        @NamedQuery(
            name = "com.example.helloworld.core.Person.update",
            query = "UPDATE Person p SET p.start=:start, p.end=:end where p.id=:id"
        )
    })
public class Person {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "weekstartdate", nullable = false)
    private String weekstartdate;

    @Column(name = "day", nullable = false)
    private String day;

    @Column(name = "start", nullable = false)
    private int start;

    @Column(name = "end", nullable = false)
    private int end;

    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(String name, String day, int start, int end, String weekstartdate) {
        this.name = name;
        this.day= day;
    this.end = end;
    this.weekstartdate=weekstartdate;
    this.start = start;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
   public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setWeekStartDate(String weekstartdate) {
        this.weekstartdate = weekstartdate;
    }

    public String getWeekStartDate() {
        return weekstartdate;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.name = fullName;
    }

    public String getDay() {
        return day;
    }

    public void setJobTitle(String day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    public int getStart() {
        return start;
    }

    public void setStart(int start) {
        this.start = start;
    }

    public int getEnd() {
        return end;
    }

    public void setEnd(int end) {
        this.end = end;
    }
}
```

Edit 2:

I am using postman and i send a person json using the put request and the url: http://localhost:8080/people/5

```
{"name":"bob man","day":"Mon","start":2,"end":175,"weekStartDate":"19-9-2016"}
```

Comment: Please update the code with the full PersonDaO and the resource and the request you are making. It appears that your person might be null in the resource.

Comment: The subject of this question is too vague, and it's not clear what's wrong.  Yes, there is a NullPointerException, but that appears to be coming from your code, and not related to Dropwizard.  Please make the question more specific.

Comment: Yes, please add the command or way you are PUTing to the `/people/{personId}` endpoint to your question. It appears you are not including a Person object in the PUT request as the data payload so it is null causing the NPE on `person.getStart()`.